# Matrix multiplication and matrix powers using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a square matrix of some probabilities, call it `Phi`, stored as a pandas Dataframe. I want to try multiplying this matrix by itself a large number of times to see what happens. I can easily 'square' the matrix [with](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```py
Phi_squared = Phi.dot(Phi)
```

I am wondering, say I want to try `Phi^1000`, is there any in-built functionality I can utilise in pandas or numpy? Or do I just need to use loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Phi**1000` where `**` is python power operator
Unless you know this converges, the result will quickly overflow and you will end up with nowhere.
Slowy increase the to the power of N and see if the result is converging, many elements goes to 0 in this case. If it diverges, many elements will increase but overflow to 0, so you better test out from small N to larger N

Comment: Oh thank you. I should have tried that. I didn't know that `**` worked with matrices too. Ideally it will converge but that's kind of what I'm testing.